# guide me to write a capacity constraint

Tags: cplex, constraint-programming, opl, cp-optimizer

I am trying to add few more constraint with existing  resource constraint project scheduling problem available OPL examples. Here I am attaching the example files of RCPSP problem. At present in this example problem I can start as many tasks as possible based on resource capacity. I want to add an additional constraint on maximum number of tasks performed in an interval variable should be less than or equal to 5. In other words simultaneously I can't do more than 5 tasks at a time.

The example problem can be located in OPL at examples/opl/sched_rcpsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use cumul function.

Before the subject to block you could write:

```
cumulFunction nbTasks = 
   sum(t in Tasks) pulse(itvs[t],1);
```

And then in the subject to block you simply add:

```
nbTasks<=5;
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, that is really helpful.